# How to ensure uniqueness in a collection of embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User (document) in which I maintain a collection of Friends (embedded document). I've been trying to make sure that for a given user, all its friends are unique (email must be unique). However that constraint isn't enforce and I can't understand why. Anybody could please help me with that?

I am using Mongo 2.2 and Mongoose.

```
var FriendSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    email            : { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, trim: true }
  , name             : { type: String, trim: true }
});


var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email            : { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }, lowercase: true, trim: true }
  , friends          : [FriendSchema]
});

UserSchema.index({ 'friend.email': 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unique indexes means that no other documents are inserted with the same value specified in the index, this doesn't apply to embedded documents. If you tried to add foo@example.com to users A and B, it should fail due to the unique index.

You would have to enforce this in Node.JS rather than trying to do it with an unique index.

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. Is it safe to let Node.js handle this? Couldn't a dupe occur during the async save call?

Comment: Yes, but there isn't really another option. You could do things like a two step save to try and reduce the chance. But at the end of the day, if the DBs not enforcing it, you will run into this issue.